# Не могу придумать больше трёх пунктов, а нужно хотя бы 4-5

Tags: текст

Составьте план текста:

Во время Первой мировой войны на канадском эскадронном миноносце служил пёс по кличке Кубрик, отличавшийся необыкновенным слухом. Заслышав шум вражеской подводной лодки, который не улавливали судовые приборы, он давал сигнал боевой тревоги. Теперь никто не скажет, сколько безвестных отважных собак погибло во время Второй мировой, разыскивая мины и спасая из-под обстрела раненых. Они и связистов заменяли пробираясь в недоступных для человека местах. Человек учит собак разыскивать людей, попавших в беду, погребённых под руинами во время землетрясений и заваленных снежными обвалами в горах, находить полезные ископаемые, пасти домашний скот. В мире немало памятников собакам. Жители одного итальянского селения поставили памятник псу по кличке Верный. В течение долгих четырнадцати лет каждый день неизменно ходил он встречать своего хозяина, убитого фашистской бомбой. (По Б. Волынкиной.)

Answer (score 0):

Для такого небольшого текста и 4 пункта будет нормально. Нашла например, такой план прям по этому же тексту от преподавателя:

1. Необычный слух пса Кубрика.
2. Подвиги псов-героев во Второй мировой войне.
3. Чему люди обучают собак.
4. Пес по кличке Верный.

Материал взят [отсюда](https://qa.studwork.org/russkiy-yazyk/1430709-sostavte-plan-teksta-vo-vremya-pervoy-mirovoy-voyny-na-kanadskom-eskadronnom-minonosce-slujil-pes-po-klichke?_ga=2.136078585.992388223.1653138781-1621621534.1653138781).